# How to concatenate multiple unicode string?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I have two unicode string `'가'` and `'ㄱ'` and I want to concatenate them to get `"가ㄱ"`

This is my code:

```
output1 = unicodeQueue(self.queue) # first unicode result
output2 = unicodeQueue(self.bufferQueue) # second unicode result
sequence = [output1, output2]
print sequence
output = ''.join(sequence)
return output
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
[u'\uac00', u'\u3131']
ㄱ가가ㄱ가
```

I don't know why it doesn't produce correct result, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.

Comment: @NPE I uploaded my partial script, the main of my question is "how to concatenate two unicode in python?"

Comment: @user1732445: there's nothing obviously wrong w/ your code.

Comment: Works for me. May be try `u''.join(sequence)`.

Comment: Same here, nothing wrong with the join, it works as supposed to the unicodeQueue class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to concatenate two strings use `+`

```
>>> '가' + 'ㄱ'
'\xea\xb0\x80\xe3\x84\xb1'
>>> u'가' + u'ㄱ'
u'\uac00\u3131'
>>> print u'가' + u'ㄱ'
가ㄱ
```

this means you can use

```
output1 + output2
```

Comment: Keep in mind that + works more slowly than `unicode.join(u'',vals)` or `str.join('',vals)`, but if it works when join doesn't, by all means, use it.